# React Hide and Show a Component only using a Start button

Tags: reactjs

I would like to hide two components in the Home component:

DisplayBox and GameBox.

When the user logs in the game starts automatically.

Instead, I'd like to only 'Show' the start button.

Then the user may press the Start button to start the game.
(will eventually have more levels to choose from in the start button component)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./home.js";
import DisplayBox from '../components/displayBox';
import GameBox from '../components/gameBox/gameBox';
import randomWords from 'random-words'
import "./home.css";

const Home = () => {
  const [numLetters, setNumLetters] = useState(5)
  const [word, setWord] = useState("")
  const [blank, setBlank ] = useState()
  console.log("Blank", blank);
  console.log("WORD", word)
  const getARandomWord = () => {
    setWord(randomWords(({ exactly: 1, maxLength: 4, formatter: (word) => word.toUpperCase() })))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getARandomWord()
  }, [])



    function clickStart(){
    // return { show: true};
    //  alert('You Start!'); 
     }

     
    return ( 
    <>
     <div> 
     <button onClick={clickStart} style={{width:"800px"}}>
          START
      </button> 
     </div> 
      <DisplayBox word={word} />
      <GameBox numLetters={numLetters} setNumLetters={setNumLetters} word={word} setWord={setWord} getARandomWord={getARandomWord} />
    
    </>
  
    
  );
};
Home.propTypes = {};
export default Home;
```

Comment: Requesting more clarification

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Hi, I'm a newbie and I edited my question, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create a new `state` to oversee whether the game is **start** or not then:-

- `Home.js`:-

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./home.js";
import DisplayBox from '../components/displayBox';
import GameBox from '../components/gameBox/gameBox';
import randomWords from 'random-words'
import "./home.css";

const Home = () => {
  const [numLetters, setNumLetters] = useState(5)
  const [word, setWord] = useState("")
  const [blank, setBlank ] = useState()
  // state to track whether the game is start or not
  const [isStart, setIsStart] = useState(false)
  console.log("Blank", blank);
  console.log("WORD", word)
  const getARandomWord = () => {
    setWord(randomWords(({ exactly: 1, maxLength: 4, formatter: (word) => word.toUpperCase() })))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getARandomWord()
  }, [])

  // handle game start
  function handleGameStart() {
    if(isStart) {
      // do something when game start
      alert('Game starting!!!')  
    
      // reset the game again
      // setIsStart(false)
    } else {
      console.log('Game is not starting!')
    }
  }

  // function to oversee what happens after game start
  useEffect(() => {
    handleGameStart()
  }, [isStart])

  return ( 
    <>
      <div> 
        <button onClick={() => setIsStart(true)} style={{width:"800px"}}>
          START
        </button> 
      </div> 
      {/* this should only be available when game has started */}
      {isStart && (
        <>
          <DisplayBox word={word} />
          <GameBox numLetters={numLetters} setNumLetters={setNumLetters} word={word} setWord={setWord} getARandomWord={getARandomWord} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

Home.propTypes = {};
export default Home;
```

Comment: Glad to help then